# Transform a set of 2d images representing all dimensions of an object into a 3d model

Tags: algorithm, 3d, textures

Given a set of 2d images that cover all dimensions of an object (e.g. a car and its roof/sides/front/read), how could I transform this into a 3d objdct?

Is there any libraries that could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "2D images" are usually called "textures". You probably want a 3D library which allows you to specify a 3D model with bitmap textures. The library would depend on platform you are using, but start with looking at OpenGL!

[OpenGL for PHP](http://phpopengl.sourceforge.net/)
[OpenGL for Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL)
... etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the links. I am using C# and need to do this from the web (asp.net).

Comment: I don't know this platform, but as I know M$ it will have its own library (like some DirectX.... I really don't know). But you might also try OpenGL, just try google.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of the program "[Poser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poser)" doing this using heuristics for human forms, but otherwise I don't believe this is actually theoretically possible. You are asking to construct volumetric data from flat data (inferring the third dimension.)

I think you'd have to make a ton of assumptions about your geometry, and even then, you'd only really have a shell of the object. If you did this well, you'd have a contiguous surface representing the boundary of the object - not a volumetric object itself.

What you can do, like Tomas suggested, is slap these 2d images onto something. However, you still will need to construct a triangle mesh surface, and actually do all the modeling, for this to present a 3D surface.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What there is currently that can do anything close to what you are asking for automagically is extremely proprietary.  No libraries, but there are some products.

This core issue is matching corresponding points in the images and being able to say, this spot in image A is this spot in image B, and they both match this spot in image C, etc.

There are three ways to go about this, manually matching (you have the photos and have to use your own brain to find the corresponding points), coded targets, and texture matching.

PhotoModeller, www.photomodeller.com, $1,145.00US, supports manual matching and coded targets. You print out a bunch of images, attach them to your object, shoot your photos, and the software finds the targets in each picture and creates a 3D object based on those points.

PhotoModeller Scanner, $2,595.00US, adds texture matching. Tiny bits of the the images are compared to see if they represent the same source area.

Both PhotoModeller products depend on shooting the images with a calibrated camera where you use a consistent focal length for every shot and you got through a calibration process to map the lens distortion of the camera.

If you can do manual matching, the Match Photo feature of Google SketchUp may do the job, and SketchUp is free. If you can shoot new photos, you can add your own targets like colored sticker dots to the object to help you generate contours.

If your images are drawings, like profile, plan view, etc. PhotoModeller will not help you, but SketchUp may be just the tool you need. You will have to build up each part manually because you will have to supply the intelligence to recognize which lines and points correspond from drawing to drawing.

I hope this helps.